# How does bash know where my variable names end?

Tags: bash, scripting

Given:

```
myvar=Hello
```

- `echo $myvar`  -> Shows `Hello`   (fine so far)
- `echo $myvar#world`  -> shows `Hello#world` (why? I thought it would complain that here is no such variable called `myvar#world`)
- `echo ${myvar#world}`  -> shows just `Hello` (again, why?)

Comment: oops, didn't know that. Have accepted some now by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The second case splits up into three parts:

```
[echo] [$myvar][#world]
 1      2       3
```

Part 1 is the command, part 2 is a parameter, and part 3 is a string literal. The parameter stops on `r` since the `#` can't be part of the variable name (#'s are not allowed in variable names.)

The shell parser will recognise the start of a parameter name by the `$`, and the end by any character which cannot be part of the variable name. Normally only letters, numbers and underscores are allowed in a variable name, anything else will tell the shell that you're finished specifying the name of the variable.

All of these will print out `$myvar` followed by six literal characters:

```
echo $myvar world
echo $myvar?world
echo $myvar#world
```

If you want to put characters which can be part of a parameter directly after the parameter, you can include braces around the parameter name, like this:

```
myvar=hello
echo ${myvar}world
```

which prints out:

```
helloworld
```

Your third case is [substring removal](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), except without a match. To get it to do something interesting, try this instead:

```
myvar="Hello World"
echo ${myvar#Hello }
```

which just prints `World`.

Comment: I got the second part, in the first case though, it is still printing out the #, so the output is Hello#world instead of Hello world

Answer (score 6):

variables cannot contain a "#" so the shell knows its not part of a variable.

The construct  ${myvar#world} actually is a string manipulator explained below:

# is actuially a string modifier that will remove the first part of the string matching "world".  Since there is no string matching world in myvar is just echos back "hello"

Answer (score 1):

"Variables" follow the rules of Shell Parameter Expansion.

The short answer is, when in doubt, you should be explicitly indicating the beginning and end of your parameters with brackets (`echo ${my_var_in_brackets}`). Shell param expansion without brackets is "unconditionally" supported, nonetheless.

So far from what I've read, I can't find a definitive answer to the question in documentation. For me this means that the *specific implementation* of bash applies some sort of Pattern Matching rule to know when the end of the variable arrives based on whitespace and special characters... The full answer is most-definitely in the gnu bash code!

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html